# Align Text to Bottom and Enforcing Overflow Hidden

Tags: html, css

I want to have a text box of fixed height where the text are aligned bottom. If the text exceeds the height of the box, the text will not be visible. My problem right now is that the `overflow:hidden;` is not hiding the extra text. I think this is because of the `display:table-cell;`. If I remove `display:table-cell;` the `overflow:hidden;` will work `vertical-align:bottom;` will no longer work.

EDIT: If the text is very long, the text needs to expand upwards until it has reached 40px. When it reaches 40px, additional text will not be rendered via `overflow:hidden;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/LxtqJ/

```
div {
    background: yellow; 
    height: 40px;
    width: 250px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    overflow: hidden;
}

<div>
    <a href="#">A SHORT LINK WITH MY TEXT</a>
</div>

<br> 

<div>
    <a href="#">A VERY...VERY LONG LINK WITH MY TEXT</a>
</div>
```

Comment: table display will make it expand, that is one of its major specifitiés

Comment: [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/LxtqJ/1/)?

Comment: @Vucko Yes, just like that. But any chance it is possible to do this without modifying the HTML structure?

Comment: @icu222much How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LxtqJ/3/), without using table-like elements?

Comment: @Vucko Your solution is close, but not exactly what I needed. Sorry, I should have been more clear. If there is a lot of text, the text needs to expand upwards until it hits the max-height value (in your example height:40px;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in HTML

```
<div class="outside">
    <div class="insideside">
        <a href="#">A SHORT LINK WITH MY TEXT</a>
    </div>
</div>

<br> 

<div class="outside">
    <div class="insideside">
        <a href="#">A VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY LONG LINK WITH MY TEXT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In CSS

```
.outside {
    background: yellow; 
    height: 40px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.insideside {
    height: 40px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Hope this will help you ...

---

You can do the same thing without editing HTML code

HTML: the same html code

CSS: Like this

```
div {
background: yellow;
height: 40px;
width: 250px;
overflow: hidden;
}

a {
display: table-cell;
height: 40px;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

maybe this will solve your problem ...

Comment: Is there a way to do this without modifying the HTML structure?

Answer (score 2):

Where you need overflow is on `<a>`

```
a {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GLidz
*(see my comment on question about display:table-XX;)*

If this is not totally what you need , you may set a max-height or height  to `<a>`

```
a {
  display:inline-block;
  max-height:2.4em /* average 2 lines 1.2 X 2 */
  /* or max-height : height of cell ;*/
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

A litlle more explanations:
table-cell will keep expand vertically , that's how it works.

1. If you set `max-height:100%;` to a child , and no `height` for
   table-cell, it will grow it will be 100% of unknown.
2. If you set an height to table-cell like `height:100px`, it will grow, but if
   childs have `height` or `max-height` like: `100%`, it will be the 100% of those 100px
   set in CSS file.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just trying to integrate your modifications into my code and verify that it is working !

Comment: Your solution is close, but not exactly what I needed. Sorry, I should have been more clear. If there is a lot of text, the text needs to expand upwards until it hits the max-height value (in your example `height:80px;`).

Comment: in that case , remove line-height and overflow. demo and answer link updated :) test with div 100px high to make it clear to see :)

Comment: The `overflow:hidden;` didn't seem to be working. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjpJh

Comment: to work it must be on <a> and a needs a size. table-cell will keep expand no matter what. it will never take overflow:hidden on vertical. It might horizontally if table-layout is set to fixed. your test doesn't follow my advise :)

Comment: added a few comments in answer. i hope you start to figure out how table-cells or td behaves :) Regards

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
div {
    background: yellow; 
    height: 40px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
div a{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```